# How to expand keyword in Clojure macro

Tags: clojure

I have the following macro:

```
(defmacro my-macro [k]
  `(do
     (def pair
        [
          k
          ~(symbol (str "-" (name k)))]
      )))
```

...which expands to:

```
(macroexpand-1 `(my-macro :n/k))

(do (def user/pair [user/k -k]))
```

...but instead I would like it to expand to

```
(do (def user/pair [:n/k -k]))
```

How can I make the macro keep the keyword and its namespace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `k` from the syntax quote using `~k`:

```
(defmacro my-macro [k]
  `(def ~'pair [~k ~(symbol (str "-" (name k)))]))
```

I've made a few other changes here as well:

- Idiomatic formatting.  Don't put `(` or `[` at the end of a line -- and put closing `)` and `]` on the same line as the expression they close.
- `do` is entirely superfluous here.
- If you want the macro to expand to `(def pair ...)`, then you need to

  1. escape out of the syntax quote (`~`)
  2. `quote` the symbol `pair` (i.e., `'pair`)

  Putting this together, you have `~'pair`.  The reason you have to do this is because, in Clojure, `` `<symbol> `` is read as `(quote <current-namespace>/foo>)`, where `<current-namespace>` stands for the current namespace.  But `def` doesn't take names that are namespaced.  Hence the `~'` dance.

  (But you *probably* want to parameterize on `pair` anyway ... otherwise, it's not very useful to use `my-macro` more than once per namespace.)

Overall, this seems like a very odd macro.  I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but I would probably take a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! The macro seems useless because I extracted it for a bigger macro that I was writing. Can you also explain why you put ~k and not both a ~ and a ' as in ~'pair?

Comment: `k` is the macro argument, so you are substituting it into the template code `(def ....)`.   `pair` is not a macro argument, so the macro will add in the current namespace unless you use this trick to suppress that.

Comment: @vidi, fair enough (on being extracted from a larger macro), but I would still question the utility of hard-coding the name `pair` in a `def` form.

Answer (score 1):

### Revised Answer

There are 2 things a bit confusing about your question & I misread it earlier.

1. You should use a regular single-quote `'` with `macroexpand-1`, not the back-tic `.  The back-tick is normally used only in a macro definition to delineate a piece of "template code".
2. I just noticed that the arg in the macro definition is `k`, and the keyword you use in the example is `:n/k`. These duplicate names will cause confusion.

Let's restate the problem:

```
(ns clj.demo)
(defmacro my-macro [arg]
  `(do
     (def pair
        [
          arg
          ~(symbol (str "-" (name arg)))]
      )))
(println (macroexpand-1 `(my-macro :n/k)))

;=> (do (def clj.demo/pair [clj.demo/arg -k]))
```

So we are in the `clj.demo` namespace, which gets applied to the symbols `pair` and `arg`.  We need to substitue the argument `arg` using `~`:

```
(ns clj.demo)
(defmacro my-macro [arg]
  `(do
     (def pair
        [
          ~arg
          ~(symbol (str "-" (name arg)))]
      )))
(println (macroexpand-1 '(my-macro :n/k)))

;=> (do (def clj.demo/pair [:n/k -k]))
```

Which is what you want.

Comment: can you explain what '~ does in this case?

Comment: I choose the other answer because the explanation felt better but I do appreciate the effort you put in explaining it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `namespace` and `name` function to extract the parts you want from the keyword passed in and combine them as required:

```
user> (defmacro my-macro [k]
        `(do
           (def pair
             [~(keyword (str (namespace k) "/" (name k)))
              ~(symbol (str "-" (name k)))])))

#'user/my-macro
user> (macroexpand-1 `(my-macro :n/k))
(do (def user/pair [:n/k -k]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I choose the other answer because extracting namespace and name and concatenating them back together with "/", although more readable for me, looks like a hack.